# Disable First and Last Buttons in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, button, repeater

```
   public void Repeater1_ItemDatabound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
            {
                Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
                b.Enabled = false;
            }

            DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            DataTable result = view.ToTable();
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == (result.Rows.Count)-1)
            {
                Button b2 = e.Item.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
                b2.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to Grey out the first and the last buttons in my asp repeater. The first Button is disabled but the last is not. Can someone point out my error.?

Comment: Wanted to point out that executing your sql script within `ItemDataBound` is a huge performance hit. It's performing your query for every data item your binding within the repeater. You might want to look at `Init` or `ItemCommand` for calculating total rows.

Comment: result.Rows.Count returns the the value that you want??

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi yes it does Debugging shows that it is reciving the correct value

Comment: it looks there is no problem.